# Compiling Openzwave's example

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, z-wave

I had succesfully installed Open-zwave on my ubuntu system with sudo make and sudo make install. After this I wanted to compile the example in this package(go in cpp/example and did "make"), but after this he show me many functions which he not found. This are located in the headerfiles. The headerfiles are included in the main and I changed nothing by the makefile which automaticly created. Had someone the same problem?
Here is an example of the errors:

/home/ubuntu/OPENZWAVE/install/open-zwave-master/cpp/examples/MinOZW/.lib/Main.o: In function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7a): undefined reference to`OpenZWave::Manager::getVersionAsString()'
Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x108): undefined reference to `OpenZWave::Options::Create(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&)'

And there are a lot of this functions missed, which are in the header(which the compiler finds...)

I compile the example with eclipse and via terminal...it's the same.

I hope somone can help. I understand not so much from write my own Makefile. If it is needed, I can copy the generated makefile here in.
Thx for your help.

Comment: Hi, I found the problem by myself.1. The header search only in one folder with "HEADER" but if I use <HEADER> and write the path in the includepath in eclipse he finds all. 2. The compiler missed the linker of openzwave and where he can finds the lib. This was the problem, why he can not finds every function,which are in the header.

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, getVersionAsString() is a very recently added static function. Most probably you have an **older** version of OpenZWave installed in your system, and the compilation is failing because it loads up the header files from there.

Have you ran `sudo make install` after the successful `make`? This should replace the old OpenZWave installation with the newer one.